# Apply each row of a matrix for polyroot in R

Tags: r

I have amatrix `m` which includes different values of coefficients of a cubic polynomial, and I want to find the maximum real root of these cubic function. How can I do this in R?

```
      m = matrix(c(1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 2, -3, -5, 6, 2), nrow = 3)
      colnames(m) <- c("d", "c", "b", "a")
```

I would like to use polyroot for each row of the `m` matrix, How can I do this in R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't this just be:

```
apply(m , 1, polyroot)
```

... remembering, of course, that the results will be in column order.

```
apply( apply(m, 1,polyroot) , 2, function(x) ifelse( abs(Im(x)) < 0.00001, x,NA))
           [,1]         [,2]          [,3]
[1,]         NA -0.416256-0i -0.4167669+0i
[2,]         NA           NA            NA
[3,] 2.34748+0i           NA            NA
```

Comment: Thanks, but How can I get just the maximum real root ?

Comment: Well, that wasn't the original question now, was it?

Comment: No, soory, I forgot to mention it.